# Need help interpreting an equation from an article (related to quaternions).

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, complex-numbers, quaternions

At this link, about half way down the page, there is an equation I don't understand

http://physicsforgames.blogspot.com/2010/02/quaternions-why.html

This is the equation.
$$VV† = -x^2I^2 - y^2J^2 - z^2K^2 - xy(IJ + JI) - xz(IK + KI) - yz(JK + KJ)$$

How is this equation created? Is the cross symbol denoting + or -?

Comment: The cross symbol denotes conjugation (if you're familiar with the complex numbers, this is the same concept being extended).  The equation is simply multiplying out $V = xI + yJ + zK$ and its conjugate, $-xI -yJ - zK$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just expanding out the product of $V = x I + y J + z K$ and $V^\dagger = -x I - y J - z K$ term-by-term.  We assume the usual distributive laws hold, but $I, J, K$ don't necessarily commute with each other.